# Counting the number of times each word appears in a range of excel cells

Tags: python, excel

Query: I want to count the number of times a certain word appears in a range of excel cells

If possible, instead of looking for a certain word, a script that summarises the number of times each word in the range of excel cells appears. i.e. to summarise in order of highest to lowest frequency, the number of times each word appears.

Excel File:

1. The cell range is in column K
2. Each cell has >1000 characters
3. There is >1000 rows

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us what you got till now?

Comment: import pandas as pd

# Insert your filename here
filename = r"C:\Users\compl\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents"+"\\"+ "TEST"

# Excel column to search through
columname = "Notes1"

# Keyword to search
Keyword = "The"

df = pd.read_excel(filename)
#print(df)


#condensed = df[df[columname].str.contains(Keyword, na=False)]
print(condensed[columname].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts())

It returns a file not found error. I'm quite new to this so any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Is it important for you that it is made in python or would VBA be ok? If you have to do it for a lot of worksheets its not a good option, if you just need to do it in a few worksheets it could be a viable option bc its easy to write and all in excel.

Comment: Only 12 sheets, so could do in VBA if you have a script for that if possible? Thanks!

Comment: I think i could come up with something, i recently mad a script with does something similar. Are the words only delimited by spaces or are there also dots and - or ; thats important to split the words correctly otherwise you could have an "something" and an "something." entry in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a function to delete all the special characters in the string you get from the cell.

```
Function without_special_chars(text As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Const special_chars As String = "-.,:;#+ß'*?=)(/&%$§!~\}][{"
For i = 1 To Len(special_chars)
text = Replace(text, Mid(special_chars, i, 1), "")
Next i
without_special_chars = text
End Function
```

This is just a function to see if the string is already in the array.

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Then you can loop through all the cells.

```
Sub query()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
Dim wordlist()
Dim nList()
Dim word As String
For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1048576, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    text = without_special_chars(ws.Cells(i, 11).Value)
    cell_words = Split(text, " ")
    For j = 0 To UBound(cell_words)
        the_word = cell_words(j)
        If j = 0 And i = 1 Then
            ReDim wordlist(0)
            ReDim nList(0)
            wordlist(UBound(wordlist)) = the_word
            nList(UBound(nList)) = 1
        Else
            If IsInArray(the_word, wordlist) = True Then
                For n = 0 To UBound(wordlist)
                    If wordlist(n) = the_word Then
                        nList(n) = nList(n) + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                ReDim Preserve wordlist(UBound(wordlist) + 1)
                ReDim Preserve nList(UBound(nList) + 1)
                wordlist(UBound(wordlist)) = the_word
                nList(UBound(wordlist)) = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
For m = 0 To UBound(wordlist)
    ws.Cells(m + 1, 1).Value = wordlist(m)
    ws.Cells(m + 1, 2).Value = nList(m)
Next
End Sub
```

For the ws you have to put in the name of your worksheet.
The last for-loop with m is the output, i just made it for testing purposes in the end you will have two arrays. wordlist which stores alle the words and nList which stores the quantity. I didnt take upper and lower case into account so its possible to have two entries for "I" and "i".

You just need to place this code in the VBA editor and run the query sub. (Open Excel, press ALT+F11, place it in ThisWorkbook, click in one line of the sub and hit run)

VBA is not very fast so i dont know how long it will take but i tested it with a few hundret cells and some sentences and it needed arround 1,5 minutes.